# How to restrict Items drag inside Jquery Sortable Widget

Tags: jquery

I am using jQuery connectedSortable widget.
This is working fine and I'm able to drag elements from table1 to table 2 and vice versa.

Is it possible to **restrict** to drag items from **table 1 to table 2 only** and not from (table 2 to table 1)

This is my code

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
        var startTable = "table1";
        var startTable2 = "table2";
        $("tbody.connectedSortable").sortable(
        {
                connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
                items: "> tr:not(:first)",
                helper: "clone",
                cursor: "move",
                zIndex: 999990,
                start: function(event, ui)
                {
                        var start_pos = ui.item.index();
                        ui.item.data('start_pos', start_pos);
                },
                receive: function(event, ui)
                {
                        var video_id = $(ui.item).attr('video-id')
                        var checkerval = checkifVideoExists(ui.item[0], video_id);
                        if (checkerval)
                        {
                                $(ui.sender).sortable('cancel');
                        }

                }
        });
});


function checkifVideoExists(elem, videoid)
{
        var flag = false;
        $('.mytable2 > tbody  > tr').each(function()
        {
                if (elem != this && $(this).attr('video-id') == videoid)
                {
                        flag = true;
                        return false;
                }
                else
                {
                        return true;
                }
        });
        return flag;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Lphf43wd/22/

Comment: i have to +1 for editor man :D

Comment: i haven't work before with `connectedSortable` but i suggest to check if `$(ui.item).closest("table").attr("id") != "videosfromtagstable"` then  `clone()` 2 tables all on receive callback,  if not get cloned back to your tables and listen to drag again.